# Script that automatically provides input() in terminal

Tags: python, input, terminal

File A is designed to automate a process and has a for loop that calls file B.

File B has an input() function, and when it is called it halts the for loop until a user input is provided.

Is there a way where I can automatically fill the user input without interrupting the for loop?
(Note: I can not change anything about File B, only File A)

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot change file B, which is the correct way to do it, I give you 3 different workarounds:

1. Patching the input function:

   ```
   import B
   B.input = lambda *args: "myinput"
   # Run function
   B.input = input
   ```
2. Patching stdin:

   ```
   import sys, io
   old_stdin = sys.stdin
   sys.stdin = io.StringIO("myinput")
   # Run function
   sys.stdin = old_stdin
   ```
3. Running File B using [subprocess.run()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run).

Option number 3 is the one I agree with the most, as it's the least hacky. Keep in mind it is the slowest option of the 3. The others are a bit dirty but can work well if you have no other option.